# MySQL ignoring duplicates on non-primary key

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert, duplicates

I have a table created by this SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id  INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I would like to insert into the table using something like

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO employees (name) values ('foo');
```

but for that statement to do nothing if there is already a person with a name **'foo'** in the table. Is there a statement out there that ignores duplicates on a field other than a primary key or a field that is defined as unique?

Comment: Create a unique key and use `INSERT IGNORE`.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO employees (name)
SELECT "foo" name FROM (select count(*) c
                        from employees
                        where name = "foo"
                        having c = 0) x;
```

You should have an index on `name` for efficiency. I'm not sure why you don't want to make it a unique index.

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7849b/1)

Comment: Is it worth mentionning that particular consideration should be given to indices in that case?

Comment: Fixed, and added a note about indexing for efficiency.